# Arduino for loop not running

Tags: arduino

What I am trying to do is to convert a string from the serial  input into individual words by detecting spaces between the words:

```cpp
String input;
char split[]{};
String output;
String product;
int inputSize;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("ready");
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        input = Serial.readString();
        input.toCharArray(split, 8);
        inputSize = sizeof(input);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++){
            if (isSpace(split[i])) {
                product = output;
                output = "";
                Serial.println(product);
            }else{
                output = output + split[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do is to convert a string from the serial input  into
individual words by detecting spaces between the words it  should
print all words sent to the serial monitor separated into  different
strings.

However sometimes it sends one word from the input string and
sometimes it doesn't send and it piles up and sends multiple words
without spaces at once

Comment: provide a sample input and the produced output for this input. why do you read a string and convert this to a char array. you could just read bytes. why do you limit your char array length 8? what if the string is longer? what if the first character is a space? you did not initialize String output... just to point out a few issues here to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, you will get the string split into the words

```
String output;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("ready");
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char input = Serial.read();
        if((input == ' ')){
          Serial.println(output);
          output = "";
        }else
        output+=input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's great that there are people like you to help others learn.